# Injected DLL as a debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, dll

Injected DLL as a debugger

So, recently I've been writing a small debugger-like program which has a simple task to read/write the EAX register value when the debugee hits the breakpoint.. Before that i spent a lot of time trying to resume the thread after it's got suspended but then i figured it out and successfully resumed the thread .. And now i'm trying to get the same program working but as a **DLL**, and to clear things up here's the theory:

1.Inject the DLL into the process

2.Set the breakpoint
3.Run the Debugging Loop (in a new thread via **CreateThread()** since it's a **DLL** and it will hang if we don't create a new thread)
4.The Debuggee crahses once it hits the breakpoint ( and this is the problem )

The strange thing is that it wasn't crashing when the debugger was an **executable program (EXE not DLL) although they both have the same code (except some minor changes)**..
And another thing to mention is that the debugging process was done through **Win32 API** Functions ..
Here's my code which is going into the thread:

```
void DebuggingLoop()
{
    DWORD Breakpoint = 0x12345678;
    DWORD dwProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();

    DebugActiveProcess(dwProcessId);

    DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(false);   

    //EnableDebuggingPrivileges(TRUE);


    DWORD dwThreadID = _GetThreadId(dwProcessId);

    HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,false,dwThreadID);

    CONTEXT ctx = {0};

    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;// | CONTEXT_CONTROL;// | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS;
    GetThreadContext(hThread,&ctx);

    ctx.Dr0 = Breakpoint;
    ctx.Dr7 = 0x00000001;
    SetThreadContext(hThread,&ctx);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    hThread = NULL;
    DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvent;
    while(true)
    {
        WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE);

        switch(dbgEvent.dwDebugEventCode)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            {
                if(dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP)
                {
                    if(dbgEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (LPVOID)Breakpoint)
                    {
                      //This Section is not being executed due to crash
                        if(hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, false, dwThreadID))
                        {
                            SuspendThread(hThread);
                            GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
                            ctx.Eax = 7;
                            SetThreadContext(hThread,&ctx);
                            ResumeThread(hThread);
                            CloseHandle(hThread);
                        }
                    }
                }
                ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId,dbgEvent.dwThreadId,DBG_CONTINUE);
                break;
            }
        default:
            ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId,dbgEvent.dwThreadId,DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED);

        }
    }
}
```

So:
 
**Q1: Is there any way to solve this problem ?  (step number 4)

Q2: Is there any way to implement debugging process other than Win32 API ?**

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure you don't pass over your ContinueDebugEvent? since you pass DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, the application may use the default handler and 'crash' in the same way an assert hits. In this sample (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the default value is DBG_CONTINUE

Comment: Thanks for replying .. and yes i'm sure because the same code was used in the [EXE] Version of this DLL and it continued and worked like a charm without crashing..